# Why my AD domain doesn't work on my laptop

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2

I have installed Windows Server 2008 R2 on a virtual machine with a **bridged** network card and installed Active Directory. I configured it and when I try to connect my laptop to the domain name, in this case, `creationsmicroweb.ca` (doesn't exist, don't try, for local only), I can't get connected.

My laptop just doesn't see it. I don't know why! There's a resume of my config:

```
Domain Name: creationsmicroweb.ca
Forest: new, principal domain controller
IP: Fixed (192.168.1.100)
DNS Name: none (just for local, I ignored them)
NETBIOS name: MICROWEB
```

If someone as found why, please help me! This is for my business that I'm starting and I can't find why it doesn't work!

Comment: I assume your laptop isn't the virtual host? :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It'll be a DNS thing.

Your laptop will need to be configured to use the DNS server of your VM.

I don't quite understand your setup (is this VM on your laptop or somewhere else?) but the typical setup is as follows:

- DNS configured when you create the server as a domain controller (install ADDS and DNS)
- DNS forwarders (or whatever) configured to point to your ISP etc
- Domain controller DNS (network properties) set to 127.0.0.1
- DHCP scopes configured to use your domain controller as DNS